# Matlab plot F-score

Tags: matlab, plot

First of all I apologize for this rather generic question. I have a data matrix where each row represent a different video and each column represent the f-measure that different object trackers achieve. I need to obtain a plot which looks like this:

[image]

I have been told that this plot can be obtained using matlab but I already checked the entire plot catalog without results..is there some magical way to obtain this that I'm missing?

Don't know if it helps, my data matrix looks like this:

```
0.5204    0.5187    0.4838    0.6406    0.4326    0.2271
0.2793    0.1177    0.1767    0.2397    0.2251    0.2138
0.2314    0.0206    0.5091    0.0698    0.4575    0.1406
0.0472    0.1602    0.6372    0.5745    0.3769    0.0294
0.1211    0.0333    0.4342    0.0801    0.0147    0.0389
0.2552    0.5786    0.2446    0.5532    0.3607    0.0984
0.0867    0.1457    0.0237    0.0294    0.1834    0.1492
0.1565    0.0973    0.1303    0.0879    0.1118    0.0756
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: The data you presented as well as the figure you have shown don't agree with each other.  The figure suggests that there are multiple `F`-scores per video. Is your data representing only **one** `F`-score per video?

Comment: Sorry my bad. In the example image the rows are not video but video categories, hence the multiple scores (one per video).

Comment: No worries.  That doesn't change the answer I put forward though.  I assumed one score per video per tracker.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [`pcolor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) function. You would call it like so:

```
pcolor(C);
```

`pcolor` creates a pseudo-coloured checkerboard plot.  You provide it a matrix `C`, and it will colour each element based on the elements provided in `C` using a `colormap`.  The default `colormap` is `jet`. The various colour maps you can use look like this:

[image: colormap]
<sub>(source: [mathworks.com](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap-dropdown.gif))</sub>

Using `jet`, bluer values tend to gravitate to lower values while red values gravitate to higher values. Given the above plot in your post, `copper` seems to be the best fit.  If you want to change the colour map, simply call `pcolor` to first produce the plot, then call `colormap(str)` where `str` is the name of the colour map you want to use.  Take note that I didn't include single quotes with the name as it isn't a string.  Also, `pcolor`'s default behaviour is that the last row and last column are not used.  However, the data **will** be used when plotting the checkerboard.  As you want to use **all** the values in your matrix, we should pad the last row and last column with the **minimum** of all of your data.  As `F`-scores contain 0, we can pad the last row and last column with zeroes.

As an example, let's create the plot using `pcolor`.  We can also specify custom x and y axis labels as well to mimic what you see above in your post's figure.  Assuming your data is stored in `A`, we can do:

```
%// Define your data matrix and store it in A first

figure;
Apad = [A zeros(size(A,1),1); zeros(1,size(A,2)) 0];
pcolor(Apad);
colormap(copper);
set(gca, 'XTick', 1.5:6.5);
set(gca, 'YTick', 1.5:8.5);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'Tracker 1', 'Tracker 2', 'Tracker 3', 'Tracker 4', 'Tracker 5', 'Tracker 6'});
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'Video 1', 'Video 2', 'Video 3', 'Video 4', 'Video 5', 'Video 6', 'Video 7', 'Video 8'});
title('Plotting F-scores for each tracker and video');
axis ij; %// Flip co-ordinate system - IMPORTANT!
```

Take a look at what I did with the those four `set` statements.  If you want the labels to be in the middle rather than where the grid is defined, I set the tick properties to start at the halfway mark in between each square, then progressed linearly by 1.  Similarly, I customized the x and y labels per tick to be Tracker 1 - 6 and Video 1 - 8.  You can change these strings to be whatever you wish that suits your purposes.  Also, take note that I had to **flip** the co-ordinate system as the origin of the data when you're plotting with `pcolor` assume that it's at the lower left corner, when your data's origin is at the top left corner.  If you want to escape this flipping, you can easily use @MacDuff's solution too.

The output I finally get is:

[image]

As you can see, darker values mean a lower `F`-score, while brighter values correspond to higher `F`-scores.  Also take note that the video labels are inverted.  Video 1 starts at the top while Video 8 is located at the bottom.  Take note of this before you start changing the y labels to suit your purposes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `pcolor` does not produce a `MxN` plot for a `MxN` matrix, but rather a `M-1 x N-1` one.

Comment: @Macduff - If you read my edit, I pad the last column and row with zeroes to plot the full matrix.  You most likely saw my post as I was editing it.

Comment: @powder - Cool!  Glad I could help!  FWIW, MacDuff's solution is also valid. It escapes having to invert the y-axis as I did.

Comment: I checked it out and yes, it's perfectly valid. Being able to customize the colors with the colormap made me choose pcolor instead of imagesc though..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `imagesc`

such as

```
imagesc(rand(3,3))
```

that will plot a 3x3 matrix. Colors are assigned automatically (minimum/maximum value = minimum/maximum color).

[image]

Comment: pcolor() allows for more customization in colors I think, but thanks anyway for the answer!

Comment: @powder - I just checked and you can customize the `colormap`.  Call up `imagesc`, then use `colormap` after to change it.  You can then use the syntax I have above to customize your x and y labels.  Make sure you take care with the y axis labels as I specified in my edit above.  In any case, either approach is good!